# Training time on GeForce GTX Titan X with CUDA 7.5

Tags: caffe

I'm running the Caffe library on GeForce GTX Titan X with CUDA 7.5 (Ubuntu 14). I'm not sure whether Caffe is properly configured for my setup. My dataset consists of images with 256 x 256 pixels (3 channels), 100000 training / 10000 test samples. For the very first test I'm using AlexNet with new_height=256, new_width=256, crop_size=227. Running 1000 training iterations on one Titan X with batch_size=256 takes about 17 minutes... Is it not too slow for this hardware?

Any help and advices are kindly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Running 1000 iterations on a batch of 256 images:
(256 height* 256 width* 256 batch size * 1000 iteration * 3 channels) bytes / ((1024*1024)MB * (17*60)seconds) = 47MBps compute speed.

The following may improve the performance:

- If the original images are of bigger resolution, try to preprocess them to 256x256 thus reducing a lot of pixel reads from the harddisk.
- Compile Caffe using Cudnn flag. This may lead to a 30% improvement in speed
- Try creating an LMDB dataset of the input set and use the LMDB data for training.
- Try using an SSD instead of a SATA harddisk.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! I will check these options.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not. Check out [this](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/performance_hardware.html) link for Caffe performance and hardware configuration.